# Single TCP retransmission causes 15 seconds delay on wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, tcpip, packet-loss

I am having a strange problem which causes long delays in http requests (POST in this case) to my own web server. This occurs only if
- a linux or Mac client is used (Windows is fine), and
- the wireless is used, cabled connection is fine
It occurs on both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz band. On the 5 GHz band, there are only 3 other AP active and I have chosen a channel which is far from those (AP auto setting also does not improve the situation). Thus I exclude external interference of the wireless as cause. Most (all?) other web sites over the same wireless are fine.

Wireshark tells me that the difference between cabled and wireless is a TCP retransmission. This results in delays of 10-20 seconds. The following image, shows
- linux on wireless -> retransmission and delay
- windows on wireless (same client) -> retransmission, no delay
- linux on cable -> no retransmission

[image]

This does not happen for all requests, but for most of them. However, the retransmission is always at the same point in the communication (the 200 OK answer to the POST request).

The best would be to find the cause of the packet loss / retransmissions, but even taking them as unavoidable, I am surprised that such few losses can result in tens of seconds of delay. My understanding is that TCP should be able to deal with it much better.

Here some details on the setup:
- Server running Ubuntu 14.04, kernel 3.13.0-042stab108.2 (inside a VM)
- Client device is running Ubuntu 12.04.5, kernel 3.2.0-97-generic, iwlwifi driver, Centrino Advanced-N 6230 AGN REV=0xB0
- Device is in a local network, NAT done by router/wifi AP FritzBox 7390, running FRITZ!OS 06.30

Comment: This is a very interesting question. Please edit your question to add a lot more detail. On which device was this packet trace taken? Exactly which OS versions are involved? Are any of these devices behind a NAT gateway? What do the working-case packet traces look like (especially the Windows case)? Can you include the full TCP session in the packet traces you provide?—I want to see the handshake and the data frames that are later Ack'd. What is the Path MTU between the client and server? Are you saying it's always the "200 OK" message that's being lost?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this @Spiff and happy new year! I have updated my question with wireshark dumps for the three cases. In fact I wasn't clear before: the TPC retransmission is also present on Windows but causes no delay. Once cabled there is no retransmission. The path MTU according to tracepath is 1500. In which way would you like to have the full TPC session (just as a screenshot of Wireshark - just larger than I did, or more details?).

Answer (score 0):

Too little too late, but I think your issue is caused by RTOs. WiFi is probably causing so many re transmits that you're hitting the Re-Transmission Timeout.

https://www.extrahop.com/company/blog/2016/retransmission-timeouts-rtos-application-performance-degradation/